# Possible to add a clickable URL using ApexPages.addMessage

Tags: visualforce, adderror

Is it possible to add a clickable url using `ApexPages.addMessage`? I am using `ApexPages.addMessage` to show an information alert but I would like to include a dynamically generated URL within the `ApexPages.addMessage`. The URL would be to a record within the same org.

Something like:

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Potential duplicate'+<a href="/o.Id">Click Me</a>))
```

I guess if this isn't possible then I will need to add my own pageBlockTable which only renders when it has a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be possible. You would want to change it to be more like this though:

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Potential duplicate <a href="' + o.Id +'">Click Me</a>'));
```

The markup will just be part of the String.

You also need to render the [`apex:pageMessage`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageMessage.htm) with `escape="false"` for the HTML to be rendered properly.